# Print something to both STDOUT and STDERR (without redirecting both to same file)

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, io-redirection

I would like to print something (e.g. the current date) to both STDOUT and STDERR, without redirecting any of them.

I tried:

```
date 1>&2
```

But I think this just redirects stdout to stderr, which is not what I want. I want to print to BOTH, without merging them in the same file.

I believe `tee` could help, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804965/how-to-tee-to-stderr

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, `tee` command is the solution:

```bash
your_command 2>&1 | tee /dev/stderr
```

The output error of your command (ie. `date`) is redirected to the standard output (with `2>&1`).
The result is doubled with `tee` command.

- One to standard output;
- The second to the file in parameter: `/dev/stderr`

Then, the result with `date` command is:

```bash
> date 2>&1 | tee /dev/stderr
Sun Dec 11 16:33:35 CET 2022
Sun Dec 11 16:33:35 CET 2022
```

So, you could redirect with `>` / `>>` and `2>` / `2>>` to any files you want:

```bash
> date 2>&1 | tee /dev/stderr >file1 2>file2
> cat file1
Sun Dec 11 16:40:59 CET 2022
> cat file2
Sun Dec 11 16:40:59 CET 2022
```

If an error occurs, with a bad command like `datex`:

```bash
> datex 2>&1 | tee /dev/stderr >file1 2>file2
> cat file1
bash: datex: command not found...
> cat file2
bash: datex: command not found...
```

Comment: Thanks. But isn't this the same as `date | tee /dev/stderr` ? It seems simpler!

Comment: slight variation: `date | tee >(cat >&2)`

Comment: @glennjackman why not `tee >(cat 1>&2)` ?  (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20553986/855050) The `1` is not needed?

Comment: @becko `date | tee /dev/stderr` do not redirect the command (`date`) error output to the pipe

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`, that's just

```
date >&1 >&2
```

In zsh, unless the `multios` option is disabled, when a fd is redirected more than once for output¹, zsh redirects it instead to a pipe and reads the data from the other end to dispatch it to the targets in a `tee`-like fashion.

In other shells, you can do the teeing with `perl` for instance:

```
date | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/=\8192} print; print STDERR'
```

On systems other than Cygwin and Linux-based ones, you can do:

```
date | tee /dev/stderr
```

On Linux/Cygwin that should be avoided as there, opening `/dev/stderr` tries to reopen the file that /dev/stderr points to anew, and writing to the resulting file descriptor is not the same as writing to stderr. It should be functionally equivalent though when stderr is open on a pipe or tty device as it often is.

---

<sup>¹  and beware that includes pipes as in `cmd >&2 | cmd2` which can be a bit surprising.</sup>